# How to embed videos in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, youtube, video-embedding

In my iphone app, I have a requirement for videos.

I want to embed the videos into the application.

I dont want that the video plays in youtube player and my application looses the control.

How to embed video in the app?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks